# R saving new column names for dataframe

Tags: r, save

I am new to R, coming from mostly Python, and still in the testing phase of whether I need both or just Python.

I imported the iris dataset from the UCI repo and changed the column names but then when I save it and load it again, it does not have the new column names.

```
# read in csv and change col names
iris = read.csv(file="/home/n/Desktop/stat3990/data/iris.data")
plot(iris[,3:4])

#install.packages("plyr")
library("plyr")
rename(iris, c("X5.1"="sepal.len", "X3.5"="sepal.wid", "X1.4"="petal.len", "X0.2"="petal.wid", "Iris.setosa"="class"))
save(iris, file="iris.rda")
load("iris.rda")
```

I have tried saving the data as `Rdata`, `.csv` but none seem to save the new columnn names.

Also this is such a famous dataset that it is weird for the column names to be so confusing in the first place but this is another issue.

Comment: You need to assign (`<-`)  `iris <- rename(iris, c("X5.1"="sepal.len", "X3.5"="sepal.wid", "X1.4"="petal.len", "X0.2"="petal.wid", "Iris.setosa"="class"))`

Comment: Not clear about the original columns in your dataset.  But, if it is the default `iris` `data(iris); iris1 <- plyr::rename(iris, c("Sepal.Length" = "X5.1", "Sepal.Width" = "X3.5"));  colnames(iris1)#
[1] "X5.1"         "X3.5"         "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"` and theen save `save(iris1, file = "iris.rda"); load("iris.rda")`

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue is that the OP didn't assign

```
iris <- plyr::rename(iris, c("X5.1"="sepal.len", "X3.5"="sepal.wid", 
        "X1.4"="petal.len", "X0.2"="petal.wid", "Iris.setosa"="class"))
```

With the assignment, the column names are changed in the original object

---

With a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
iris1 <- plyr::rename(iris, c("Sepal.Length" = "X5.1", "Sepal.Width" = "X3.5")); 
save(iris1, file = "iris.rda")
load("iris.rda")
```